# Как переиспользовать Rest запрос в одном классе Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Всем привет. В ходе реализации столкнулся с такой проблемой, что необходимо создать сущность, которая будет использоваться около 5 раз в одном классе. Код следующий:

```
        val token = Service.getAuthToken();
        val object = new RequestWrapper("***");
        
        val payload = new RequestPayload(dto.getSomething());
        object.setPayload(payload);

        val httpEntity = getRequestEntity(object, token);
        val httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST;
        val response = restTemplate.exchange(adapterExecUrl,
                httpMethod, httpEntity, ResponseWrapper.class);

        if (response.getBody() == null || response.getBody().getPayload() == null)
            throw new RequestErrorException("An error occured during request");

        if (response.getBody().getPayload().getStatus() != 0)
            throw new RequestErrorException("Request " + object.getPayload().getMethod() + " returned != 0");

        return response.getBody().getPayload().getTargetSum();
```

Повторятся будет следующий отрывок:

```
        val httpEntity = getRequestEntity(object, token);
        val httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST;
        val response = restTemplate.exchange(adapterExecUrl,
                httpMethod, httpEntity, ResponseWrapper.class);

        if (response.getBody() == null || response.getBody().getPayload() == null)
            throw new RequestErrorException("An error occured during request");

        if (response.getBody().getPayload().getStatus() != 0)
            throw new RequestErrorException("Request " + object.getPayload().getMethod() + " returned != 0");
```

Comment: Почему у вас тег Java? В java разве есть ключевое слово val? Если для вас Java и Kotlin одно и тоже то вынужден огорчить. И вам стоит различать их, так как могут быть проблемы и баги в будущем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете выделить повторяющийся код в отдельную функцию и вызывать эту функцию несколько раз в своем классе.
private ResponseWrapper executeRequest(RequestWrapper object, String token,

```
String adapterExecUrl) {
        val httpEntity = getRequestEntity(object, token);
        val httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST;
        val response = restTemplate.exchange(adapterExecUrl,
                httpMethod, httpEntity, ResponseWrapper.class);

        if (response.getBody() == null || response.getBody().getPayload() == null)
            throw new RequestErrorException("An error occured during request");

        if (response.getBody().getPayload().getStatus() != 0)
            throw new RequestErrorException("Request " + object.getPayload().getMethod() + " returned != 0");

        return response.getBody();
}
```

Затем в вашем классе:

```
val token = Service.getAuthToken();
val object = new RequestWrapper("***");
val payload = new RequestPayload(dto.getSomething());
object.setPayload(payload);

val response = executeRequest(object, token, adapterExecUrl);

return response.getPayload().getTargetSum();
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо=)